# Convert linux shell command to win10 powershell

Tags: android, linux, powershell

Below command works on linux, how can I make it work in windows powershell?

```
adb shell cat /proc/$\(pidof system_server\)/statm
4598780 53137 53137 7 0 489297 0
```

Comment: Start by figuring out what info you are trying to get. `statm` returns process memory usage, and there are a few ways to get similar info from Windows. What is the best depends on what is needed.

Comment: Can you please clarify: on which system do you want to issue that command and which system do you want to query with that command? Otherwise, I would say, just install `adb` and issue the same command.